# How do I use javascript form validation with custom instead of pseudo classes for valid states?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, frontend

I want to have exact control over when the validity state is displayed to a user with CSS using vanilla js. I opted for assigning custom classes instead of styling input:invalid and input:valid, but the solution I came up with doesn't work. I'm new to forms and it's possible that my entire logic for this solution is flawed, but everything other than assigning classes seems to be working (setting and reporting CustomValidity).

I made this CodePen to demonstrate my problem: https://codepen.io/kmekmekme/pen/qBQNggb

```
    const firstName = document.querySelector("#first-name");
    firstName.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        firstName.setCustomValidity("");
        var val = firstName.validity.valid;
        firstName.classList.remove("valid");
        firstName.classList.remove("invalid");
        if (val == false) {
            if (firstName.validity.tooShort) {
                firstName.setCustomValidity("First name must be 2 letters or longer.");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    firstName.reportValidity();
                    firstName.classList.add("invalid"); }, 900); }
            else if (firstName.validity.patternMismatch) {
                firstName.setCustomValidity("First name can only contain letters");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    firstName.reportValidity();
                    firstName.classList.add("invalid"); }, 900); } }
        else if (val==true) {
            firstName.classList.add("valid");
            firstName.setCustomValidity(""); } })
```

I apologize if this question might be specific or not helpful to other users, but I can't figure it out on my own with Google.

In this example, I'm trying to remove both classes at every user input, but I've also tried removing one class every time the other class is assigned (ex. firstname.classList.remove("valid"); firstName.classList.add("invalid");). The other solution seems to work better than the first one but it's still buggy. I'm trying to achieve a real-time response to wrong input, so using a "change" event doesn't produce what I want.

Edit: When I just remove the timeout I set, the function seems to work fine. I need a way to make my reports still work real time but without having the input field turn red as soon as you start typing (because you initially need to have only one letter). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Your CodePen link is broken.

Comment: codepen link fixed !

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the input event is triggered before the validity state is updated. So when you check firstName.validity.valid, it still has the previous value. That's why the class assignments are not working as expected.
To fix this, you can use the change event instead of input to update the validity state and assign classes. The change event is triggered after the validity state has been updated.
Here's an updated version of your code that uses the change event:

```
const firstName = document.querySelector("#first-name");
firstName.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  firstName.setCustomValidity("");
  firstName.classList.remove("valid");
  firstName.classList.remove("invalid");
  
  if (!firstName.checkValidity()) {
    if (firstName.validity.tooShort) {
      firstName.setCustomValidity("First name must be 2 letters or longer.");
    } else if (firstName.validity.patternMismatch) {
      firstName.setCustomValidity("First name can only contain letters");
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      firstName.report
```

In this code, the change event is used instead of input. The checkValidity() method is called to update the validity state, and then the classes are assigned based on the validity state. I've also removed the unnecessary checks like val == false and val == true since checkValidity() already returns a boolean value.
With these changes, the classes should be assigned correctly based on the validity state of the input field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I'm trying to achieve a real-time response to wrong input, so using a "change" event doesn't produce what I wanted. However, when I just remove the timeout I set, the function seems to work fine. I need a way to make my reports still work real time but without having the input field turn red as soon as you start typing (because you initially need to have only one letter). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: To achieve real-time validation without immediate feedback, you can use a debounce mechanism on the input event to delay the validation logic. Additionally, handle the invalid event to trigger the reportValidity() method with a slight delay (e.g., using setTimeout) for visual updates. This approach ensures validation occurs after a pause in typing and provides a smoother user experience.

Comment: Thank you, I've now managed to write a working function for this problem with your help. If you want, you can edit your original answer or post another one and I will mark it as a correct solution.